# Is this possible to get one XMR?

Tags: monerod, mining

`monerod` shows this when I type status:

```
Height: 2377895/2377895 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining at 3.30 kH/s, net hash 2.68 GH/s, ...
```

Is this possible to get one XMR?

Comment: Height: 2378401/2378401 (100.0%) on mainnet, mining at 3.30  kH/s, net hash 2.58 GH/s, v14, 12(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 16h 28m 53s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you start mining it's *possible*, but it's better to work out your likelihood or probable timeframe for mining a block (currently ~1 XMR).

Your *chance* of mining the next block is:

```
3.3e3 / 2.68e9
0.0000012
```

And you *should* find a block in:

```
network hashrate / your hashrate / network blocks per day
2.68e9 / 3.3e3 / 720
1128 days
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is the expected time to a block, and the variance will be huge.